# Set checkbox/radiobox to add additional cmd params to a JButton?

Tags: java, swing

As it goes, I've got *many* checkboxes/radio boxes, first of all, the main jButton is "RunGameButton" and then I've got the code for it here

```
private void RunGameButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    try
    {
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start C:\\mygame\\game.exe");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
    }

}
```

And say, for example, I have a checkbox titled "NoMonstersBox" and when checked, it would add the -nomonsters command to the launch of mygame.exe to the code of "RunGameButton" like so

```
private void RunGameButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    try
    {
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start C:\\mygame\\game.exe -nomonsters");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
    }

}
```

But, me being pretty much a newbie, I don't know where to put what, or what to put where. And extensive googling results in nothing useful.

EDIT

Here's my current bit as requested

```
private void RunGameButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
try
{
   if(CheatsBox.isSelected())
   {
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start C:\\mygame\\game.exe +SV_CHEATS 1");
   }
   if(NoMonstersBox.isSelected())
   {
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start C:\\mygame\\game.exe -nomonsters");
   }
   else
   {
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start C:\\mygame\\game.exe");    
   }
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    //Log Error
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `NoMonsters` flag is denoted by a checkbox with name `chkNoMonsters`, what you could do would be to augment your `RunGameButtonActionPerformed` event handler to take the state of the checkbox in consideration, something like so:

```
private void RunGameButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    try
    {
       if(chkNoMonsters.isSelected())
       {
           Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start C:\\mygame\\mygame.exe -nomonsters");
       }
       else
       {
           Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start C:\\mygame\\game.exe");    
       }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        //Log Error
    }
}
```

Also as a side note, it is considered back practice to catch exceptions and not do anything about them. The least you usually do is to log them, so that you are aware that something broke.

EDIT: As per your question edit, the main issue is that you have 2 sets of conditions groups. The first set is denoted by this `if` statement: `if(CheatsBox.isSelected())` and the second set is deonted by `if(NoMonstersBox.isSelected())... else...`.

To ensure that your game runs only once, you need to collapse your two sets of condition groups into one set. To do this, you just need to replace `if(NoMonstersBox.isSelected())` with `else if(NoMonstersBox.isSelected())`. This will make sure that only one condition of the 3 is selected.

This however, will make your choices mutually exclusive, meaning that you won't be in a position to have both the `NoMonsters` and the `+SV_CHEATS 1` flags enabled. To go around this, what you could do would be to use the [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class, something like so:

```
private void RunGameButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    try
    {
       //Basic game launching command.
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("cmd.exe /C start C:\\mygame\\game.exe");
       if(chkNoMonsters.isSelected())
       {
           //Add the No Monsters Flag
           sb.append(" -nomonsters");
       }
       if(CheatsBox.isSelected())
       {
           //Add the Cheats Flag
           sb.append(" +SV_CHEATS 1");           
       }

       //Launch the game
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sb.toString());
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        //Log Error
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but upon trying to add another section for my "CheatsBox" checkbox, and clicking Run Game after checking (only) the Cheats Enabled checkbox, it runs the game, but twice. Is there another piece of code I'm missing?

Comment: @Loismustdie555: Please post the section you have added.

Comment: Can't figure out how to do it in a comment. I'll edit the post

Comment: Barring editing my post again, I'll use pastebin. On attempting to set up so if *both* are checked, it doesn't work. What am I missing here?

http://pastebin.com/3SH4X9Hm

Comment: It does help, but another issue arose, in my just previous comment.

Comment: @Loismustdie555: This: `else if(NoMonstersBox.isSelected())
            if(CheatsBox.isSelected())` needs to be `else if(NoMonstersBox.isSelected() && CheatsBox.isSelected())`. Also, that condition must be placed on top. If you select both check boxes, the first `if` statement will evaluate to `true` and the remainder of the condition set will be ignored. Please refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) tutorial for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much @npinti ! 
Your answer (and edited answers, lol) are exactly what I needed.